# Enable passwordless access to MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, authentication

How can I delete my password for MySQL? I dont want to have a password to connect to the database. My server is running Ubuntu.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, why don't you want a password?

Comment: For Example I run into errors when I run "dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin". It stops with error 1045 with access denied root@localhost "password: no" ending.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Personally, I think instead it's better to set a password and save it in /root/.my.cnf:

First:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'asdfghjkl'
```

Then edit root's .my.cnf file:

```
[client]
password = asdfghjkl
```

Make sure to `chmod 0600 .my.cnf`.

Now you have a password but you're no longer prompted for it.  My default MySQL server install is a totally random unique password for each MySQL server, saved in the .my.cnf file like this.

Comment: I strongly agree with the setting your environment to automatically authenticate you vs removing the password.

Comment: You may need quotes around that password in the .my.cnf.  It didn't work for me without.

Comment: @user67641: Might depend on version and what's in your password...  Mine are all long random strings of alphanumerics (no special characters) and haven't needed quotes.

Comment: If you need to create /root/.my.cnf, it's worth explicitly setting 0600 permissions on it to be sure no other user can snoop. Most of the time normal users can't descend into /root, but the extra paranoia is almost always warranted.

Comment: Missing  `mv ./+%Y%m%d`.$db.sql $OUTPUT` between mysqldump and gzip

Answer (score 18):

Yes, less passwords can be a good thing.
But don't just open the database for everybody.

via unix_socket:

```
grant usage on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified via unix_socket;
```

This gives you passwordless mysql acces for a locally logged in root user.
Btw. this is the default in recent ubuntu / debian releases.

```
some_user@box: mysql -u root  # denied
root@box: mysql               # good
some_user@box: sudo mysql     # good, if "some_user" has sudo rights.
```

Explanatory slides: https://www.slideshare.net/ottokekalainen/less-passwords-more-security-unix-socket-authentication-and-other-mariadb-hardening-tips.

Comment: Welcome to SF!  Lovely first answer: clear, a good summary, a link for further exploration, and it adds something to the existing corpus of answers.  I'm delighted to be your first upvote, and I hope you stay around to write more answers like this one.

Comment: The slides are okay, but this is the actual documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

Answer (score 10):

If you DO have a password set for MySQL, follow the instructions at [Recover MySQL root Password](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html), and then set your password to null:

**For 5.7.6 and later**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass'
```

**For 5.7.5 and earlier**

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("") where User='root';
```

* needs a DB restart (see instructions at the link) for this to take effect.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: in this case, dont forget to "flush privileges;"

Comment: @meyosef - please mark an answer as answered if it solved your problem (click on the green checkmark under the number of votes).

Comment: I thought I could use empty password just for Unix socket and not loopback, but it's not possible. The `unix_socket` plugin does a slightly different thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by '';
```

Answer (score 4):

The `IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket` statement is only for MariaDB.

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
```

For MySQL, the same is achieved by `IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket`.

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```

Only a difference of two words, but they're really not the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that by default there is no password if your the admin user and accessing it locally.   Are you finding something different than that?

Does this work?

```
#> mysqladmin -u root password ''
```